# Difference between forecast, estimation, projection, prediction?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics

Could someone explain me the difference between those terms. For me all of them are somehow synonymous. Thanks in advance!

Comment: These are not strictly mathematical terms.  English language terms are ambiguous by nature.  That said, I would separate "estimation" from the others.  Either mathematically or in English usage, that term suggest a hard quantity which, for whatever reason, we can't measure exactly and for which we therefore seek an approximate value.  Very different from anything predictive.

Comment: Thanks, but whats then the difference between approximation and estimation?

Comment: What i found out so far is. Roughly speaking estimation=approximation. Forecasting is a way of prediction, hence predicition is a more general term.

Comment: Again, you are asking about English usage, not math.  Personally, I would not distinguish between forecasting and prediction though I have seen some people reserve "forecast" for a prediction based solely on historical observations (while of course "predictions" are free to draw from all sorts of things).  But, really, these are not precise terms and, if you intend to use them in a mathematical context, you should define what clearly what you are doing.

Comment: "estimation" does not have as much of a forward-looking sense as the others, but I would not regard it as "approximation"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Language is often inexact, but in terms of how I've seen the words used in mathematics and statistics:

- **Approximation** happens when you have a value, or a function, that is difficult to calculate, and so you replace it with a simpler calculation. In more rigorous contexts, this usually includes some exploration of the error involved. For example, using $\pi = \frac{22}{7}$ is an approximation with an error of about 0.04%. Approximations often relate to asymptotic behaviours, i.e. an approximation for a function is often expressed in relation to how the error behaves in some kind of limit.
- **Estimation** happens when you have a quantity you can't measure directly, but you can use a random mechanism to guess its value. For example, I roll a die 100 times and I get 20 rolls of 1, so I estimate that it has a 20% probability of rolling a 1, with a standard deviation of 4%.
- **Forecasting** and **prediction** are, to me, the same thing. They both involve having a sequence of data, and building a model based on that data to predict something about a future data point. For example, I can look at the price of Bitcoin over the past year, and if I assume it follows a certain pattern then I expect that its value tomorrow is going to be 2% higher than its value today.

Comment: thank you very much for the kind explanation.

Comment: Note that this answer is just an approximation of the truth